# ShellScript - IF handling filename pattern

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I have a directory in UNIX which has a thousands of .TGZ compressed files, they follow this pattern :

```
01.red.something.tgz
02.red.something.tgz
03.red.anything.tgz
04.red.something.tgz
01.blue.something.tgz
02.blue.everything.tgz
03.blue.something.tgz
04.blue.something.tgz
01.yellow.something.tgz
02.yellow.blablathing.tgz
03.yellow.something.tgz
04.yellow.something.tgz
```

They are using a large amount from the filesystem,and i need to list them without extract the file itself. Actually it'll take some time, so i believe this shellscript will fit the need. I'm kinda new to Shellscript, i'm learning so i made this .sh

```
$pattern = "red"

for file in *.tgz
do

    if [[ ${file} == '...${pattern}.*.tgz' ]]; then
        echo" ==>  ${file} match the pattern and the output dir is : out/"
        tar -tf $file > ./out/$file
    else
        echo "${file} Doesn't match the pattern"
    fi
done
```

But i've made something wrong in the **if** part,and even when the pattern is matched, i've got the '**Doesn't match the pattern**' message.

I Know it's kinda simple **if**,but i can't understand why this fella doesn't work. I'd be thankfull if you guys can explain why this doesn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: `==` is not the match operator; read up on `globbing` and use `*.${pattern}.*.tgz` directly in the for-loop

Comment: Thank you,i'll do some search about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to watch out for spaces when you create varibales in bash, in `if` there should not be `'` - single quotes or `"` - double quotes if you want to match on `regex`, 
use: `if [[ ${file} == ${regEx} ]];`

Test:

```
$ ls *.tgz
01.red.something.tgz  01.yellow.something.tgz
$ ./t.sh
 ==>  01.red.something.tgz match the pattern and the output dir is : out/
01.yellow.something.tgz Doesn't match the pattern
```

---

```
$ cat t.sh
#!/bin/bash

pattern="red"
regEx="*.${pattern}.*.tgz"

for file in *.tgz
do
    if [[ ${file} == ${regEx} ]]; then
        echo " ==>  ${file} match the pattern and the output dir is : out/"
        #tar -tf $file > ./out/$file
    else
        echo "${file} Doesn't match the pattern"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you friend, it's working like a charm . I understood the concept and i'll be aware next time. :)

Comment: great - consider accepting this as an answer and up vote : ) [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)